# Get 404 in prod server but local everything work nginx

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
... 
 frontend:
    container_name: docker-frontend
    build: ./frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    command: serve -s dist/vu4y-frontend -l 4200
    networks:
      - docker-network

  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: docker-nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend
    networks:
      - docker-network
...
```

Nging config app.conf file:

```
server {
  listen 80;

  server_name mysite.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://frontend:4200;
  }
}
```

This work fine. But after some updates stopped work. I returned everything back, but it still doesn't work. I alredy try rerun server and remove docker nginx image in container, it doesn't work.

When i run localy everything work fine. But in prod server I see 404. Maybe there is any cache in nginx or something else.

In log files I don't see any error.

```
....


docker-nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
docker-nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
alienmova-docker-nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
docker-nginx | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: IPv6 listen already enabled
docker-nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
docker-nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
docker-nginx | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.22.0
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 11.2.1 20220219 (Alpine 11.2.1_git20220219) 
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.4.0-122-generic
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 23
docker-nginx | 2022/07/14 19:53:51 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 24


....


docker-nginx | 159.223.63.89 - - [14/Jul/2022:20:03:05 +0000] "GET /cms/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 1653 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
docker-nginx | 159.223.63.89 - - [14/Jul/2022:20:03:05 +0000] "GET /sito/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml HTTP/1.1" 404 1653 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36" "-"
docker-nginx | 159.223.63.89 - - [14/Jul/2022:20:03:06 +0000] "" 400 0 "-" "-" "-"
```

Any help will very usefull.

Comment: I have just recreated the server and everything right now working.

Answer (score 0):

this could be abit off topic but if its a production server you should not serve your angular app using `ng serve` in production as this will take up more server resources , as the command makes your code keep waiting for changes and rebuild if any.

For Production use `ng build --prod` then let nginx serve the dist folder